# Add Class Jquery Append + Each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a problem, i have a while to get information in JSON and i want add an ID on each element but my code doesnt work.

The append work, i have all my result in JSON but the class test doesnt work.

```
    <style type="text/css">
      .test
     {
    color:red;
    }

 </style>
 <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({


        url: 'https://world.openfoodfacts.org/cgi/search.pl?search_terms=<?php echo $_POST['search']; ?>&search_simple=1&action=process&json=1',
        dataType: 'json',
       success: function(json) {


       var count = 1;

         $.each(json.products, function(i, obj) {

         window["var" + count] = $('<a href="#null">' + obj.generic_name_fr + ' - ' + obj.brands + '</a>'); 
         $("#push").append(window["var" + count]);
         window["var" + count].addClass('test');

        count++;



             });




        }

            }); });



        </script>

        <ul data-role="listview" id="push" style="margin-top:25px;">

               </ul>
```

thanks :)

Comment: I'm so confused. What is the purpose of adding the DOM elements to global variables like that if the only thing they are used for is to append onto the `#push` element?

Comment: I don't know, this is the only solution I found, i just need to append the result JSON on a div with this form : "<a href="#" name="recupinfoproduits"> obj.generic_name_fr </a>. I tried several solutions to add the "name" and I did not succeed

Comment: Also, since you are hard-coding the HTML, why not just put `<a class="test" href="...">..`?

Comment: The class its just for test, i need to add the attr "name" , but its not possible with an append ;)

Comment: Alright, I'll put together an answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what your question is, but try this (**updated solution**)

```
$(document).ready(function domReady() {
    $.getJSON('https://world.openfoodfacts.org/cgi/search.pl?search_terms=<?php echo $_POST["search"]; ?>&search_simple=1&action=process&json=1')
        .done(function success(response) {
            var links;

            links = $(response.products.map(function toProductLink(product, index) {
                var id;

                id = index + 1;

                return $('<a href="#">')
                    .text(product.generic_name_fr)
                    .attr('id', 'product-link-' + id)
                    .attr('name', 'recup'),
                    .data('calories', product.energy);
            }));

            links.appendTo($('#push'));
        })
        .fail(function fail() {
            console.error(arguments);
        });
});
```

Comment: You are right, a single comma was missing, and the embedded PHP code may also have triggered your linting senses.

Comment: Yes, the comma was missing, and the single quote terminated the string... resulting in a syntax error. 2 syntax errors in, what, 25 lines of code?

Comment: Well, the PHP code would have evaluated before that ever became a problem. I apologize for being a bit too fast on the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesnt work

I'm sorry i'm not have a good english

Without my code i explain my problem, i have the JSON return and i want to put each element on a DIV.

On my div i need exactly that :

```
 <div id="push">
   // Fist element    <a href="#" name="recup" data-calories='JSON.PRODUCTS.ENERGY'> json.products.generic_name_fr </a>
   // Second element    <a href="#" name="recup" data-calories='JSON.PRODUCTS.ENERGY'> json.products.generic_name_fr </a>
  </div>
```

It's just that, but its not easy to add ATTR on an append with a json while